# Setting $_POST checkboxes by default for PHP search

Tags: php, html, search, post, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes used for searching

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" ',$var1 ? ' class="checkon" checked="checked"' : '','name="c1" value="c1">
<input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" ',$var2 ? ' class="checkon" checked="checked"' : '',' name="c2" value="c2">';
<input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" ',$var3 ? ' class="checkon" checked="checked"' : '',' name="c3" value="c3">';
```

I want them to all be on by default, but if I set them to on:

```
$_POST['c1'] = 'on';
```

Then when I uncheck the box it is still on? How do I get it on by default but off when I uncheck it?

Comment: I guess you should initialize your variables `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3` to true when the form is not yet submitted

Comment: Do you mean like; if (!isset($_POST['c1'])) {$var1 =  true;}

Comment: Yeah, something like that

Comment: OK, the problem is that it still will not uncheck!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you have an onChange event with these inputs. You should let the user check and uncheck whichever boxes they want and then submit all the data together. Then do if(isset($_POST['c1'])){ //Box was checked }. Also have checked="checked" just as a HTML attribute (so `<input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="on" checked="checked" />`) rather than doing a shorthand if statement in an onChange event.

Here would be the way I would do it:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
     <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="on" <?php if (isChecked('c1')) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
     <input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="on" <?php if (isChecked('c2')) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
     <input type="checkbox" name="c3" value="on" <?php if (isChecked('c3')) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
    function isChecked($name) { //Darkbee's edit
        return empty($_POST) || isset($_POST[$name]);
    }
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if(isset($_POST['c1'])){
         //Checkbox1 was checked when the form was submitted, code goes here
      }
      //Do the same for c2 & c3 as necessary
   }
?>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This is not right. Checkboxes will always be on. OP only wants this in initial state. After a POST happend, he only wants to see the one that were actually checked

Comment: Erm, pretty sure it is right. The checkboxes will be on when the page is first loaded. Then a user can uncheck them if necessary. The checks within PHP are issets to detect whether or not a variable was actually set for each corresponding input. If a user unticked a checkbox then no "on" variable will be set.

Comment: If user unchecks box 1 and 3 and then do a post, he will see all checkboxes as checked again. See edit

Comment: Yes you're correct, I have seen the browser remember in the past but having tested a few browsers this is not the case with all. I just pressed approve on your edit and it said it had already been rejected?

Comment: Browser remembering checkboxes is due to browser cache, better to explict prevent that from. my edit was : http://pastebin.com/fuKYuY6c